# ajax http 500 error while editing panel in drupal 7

Tags: ajax, panels

I am getting this error when I tried to edit my panel in drupal 7.

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
>
> HTTP Result Code: 500
>
> Debugging information follows.
>
> Path: /panels/ajax/editor/edit-pane/panel_context%3Apage-contacts%3A%3Apage_contacts_panel_context%3A%3A%3A%3A/8
>
> StatusText: Internal Server Error
>
> ResponseText: 500 - Internal server error.
>
> Server Error 500 - Internal server error.

Anyone with solution highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Check your php error logs and see if you can find anything useful to add in there.

Comment: how can i check my php error logs?

Comment: That depends on your environment, I suggest [googling that](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=check%20php%20error%20logs)

Comment: nothing in error logs

Answer (score 1):

Please check below configuration & update :

**php.ini**

> max_execution_time = 30 --> 60 ;
>
> memory_limit = 32 --> 128, or even 256M ;

**.htaccess**

Add the below lines :

> php_value auto_append_file none
>
> php_value memory_limit 128M

**my.ini**

> max_allowed_packet = 4M --> 64M